# Trim filename but keep file extension

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Does anyone know how to trim a string/filename but keep the file extension?

For example:

I would like **Picture1.jpg** to become **Pic.jpg**.

I've been playing around with the `StrUtils` unit without being able to work out a solution. `LeftStr` was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: What rules do you want to use to construct the trimmed version and how do you want to avoid ambiguity?  E.g. what do to about Picture2.jpg when Pic.Jpg is already  in use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the name into stem and extension. Shorten the stem. Then re-combine. Like this:

```
function ReduceFileName(const FileName: string; const MaxStemLength: Integer): string;
var
  Ext: string;
  StemLength: Integer;
begin
  Assert(MaxStemLength > 0);
  Ext := ExtractFileExt(FileName);
  StemLength := Length(FileName) - Length(Ext);
  if StemLength <= MaxStemLength then begin
    Result := FileName;
    exit;
  end;
  Result := Copy(FileName, 1, MaxStemLength) + Ext;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much David, this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: There is also a method called `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` which can be used to return only the filename without file path and file extension. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetFileNameWithoutExtension You can use this method to quickly extract relevant part of file name.

Comment: You can also use `ChangeFileExt()` with a blank `Extension` parameter to remove the extension.